# Initializing a timer for each button inside datagrid clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, datagrid

I want to initalize a timer when I click a button on a specific datagrid row.

For example: I have multiple rows with a play button, when pressed I'd like to start a timer on that specific row **only** and when paused I'd like to only pause that one timer.

Here's the C# code so far.

```
private void OnPlayButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedProject = ((FrameworkElement) sender).DataContext as Project;

    if (selectedProject != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Selected Project has been played: " +
            selectedProject.ProjectName + " : Billed Hours - " +
            selectedProject.ActualBilledHours);

        if (ProjectDictionary.ContainsKey(selectedProject))
        {
            ProjectDictionary.Remove(selectedProject);

            var toggle = IsPlaying = !IsPlaying;
            ProjectDictionary.Add(selectedProject, toggle);

            foreach(var dict in ProjectDictionary)
            {
                if (dict.Key == selectedProject)
                {
                    if (toggle)
                        Timer.Start();
                    else
                        Timer.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would the sender in this case not be the button?

Comment: Could you initialize multiple timers for each row, and start/stop a specific timer by your clicked row index?

Comment: It would be easy with MVVM, just use Timer as field in your model and raise it on Play button clicked

Comment: Or, if mvvm is impossible for some reason, you can do this some dirty way: 
In your ProjectDictionary<project, toggle> you could use <project,KeyValuePair<toggle, timer>> or even with tuple <project, Tuple<toggle, timer>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a global timer for all rows. Your question is a bit unclear but if you want a timer per row, you could for example store a timer per `Project` object in a dictionary. Something like this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Project, Timer> _timers = new Dictionary<Project, Timer>();
private void OnPlayButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedProject = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as Project;

    if (selectedProject != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Selected Project has been played: " +
            selectedProject.ProjectName + " : Billed Hours - " +
            selectedProject.ActualBilledHours);

        if (ProjectDictionary.ContainsKey(selectedProject))
        {
            ProjectDictionary.Remove(selectedProject);

            var toggle = IsPlaying = !IsPlaying;
            ProjectDictionary.Add(selectedProject, toggle);

            foreach (var dict in ProjectDictionary)
            {
                if (dict.Key == selectedProject)
                {
                    //get the timer from the dictionary
                    Timer timer;
                    if (!_timers.TryGetValue(selectedProject, out timer))
                    {
                        timer = new Timer();
                        _timers.Add(selectedProject, timer);
                    }

                    //start or stop
                    if (toggle)
                        timer.Start();
                    else
                        timer.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't use your exact way but it gave me an idea how to sort my problem, so thanks.